# Codesandbox decides on the wrong port as the main browser port

Tags: codesandbox

I have a codesandbox project that uses concurrently to run both frontend and backend using `concurrently`.

The `react-scripts` dev server runs on port 3000, and the api server runs on port 3000.

In the top bar of the project, codesandbox decides that the `api` server is the "main" and directs the browser to it.

Probably because the `api` server starts faster, and listens first to the 3002 port.

I want codesandbox to use the 3000 port as the main port - how do I configure that?

Here's my codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/remult-react-todo-4ztjw

[image]

The browser tabs in codesandbox, I want 3000 to be the main browser

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it from the setting menu:

[image: Codesandbox settings menu]

If you haven't, click on `sandbox.config.json`, it will create the file for you.

The file contents will look more or less like:

```json
{
  "template": "node",
  "container": {
    "node": "16",
    "port": 3000
  }
}
```